# How to solve php REDIRECTION ISSUE

Tags: php

```
<?php
/* subject and email varialbles*/

$emailSbuject = 'Subscribe';
$webMaster = 'help@intaxfin.com';
$emailSbuject2 = 'Thank you';
$client = ' $emailFeild\r\n';
/*gathering data variables*/

$emailFeild = $_POST['email'];

// admin message body
$body= <<<EOD
Our new subscriber is $emailFeild

Email: $emailFeild 
EOD;

$textMessage = <<<EOD

        Thank you for subscribing us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible.

EOD;
    $headers = "From: $emailFeild\r\n";
    $header = "From: $noreply@example.com";
    $success = mail($webMaster,$emailSbuject,$body,$headers);
    $success1 = @mail($emailFeild,$emailSbuject2,$textMessage,$header);
    /*Result*/


    $theResults = <<<EOD
EOD;

echo  "$theResults";

header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit;
?>
```

I have lots of html pages under every page. I have a text box and button with a php script associated with it.

My problem is whenever I put my email id and clicks that button it will redirect me to the home page which is www.example.com. I want to stay to that exact page.

Comment: you are redirecting to home page, not an specific page. write a condition to redirect a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

If you show form in each page then just add to form hidden input and store in this input current url

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>" />
```

In your script check this param and make redirect to url

```
if (isset($_POST["redirect"]) && $_POST["redirect"] != "") {
  $redirect_to = $_POST["redirect"];
} else {
  $redirect_to = "/";
}
header("Location:" . $redirect_to);
```